# Python checking if a fork() process is finished

Tags: python, fork

Just wondering if some one could help me out. The problem I'm having is that I os.fork() to get several bits of information and send them to a file, but checking to see if the fork process is not working.

```
import sys
import time
import os
import re


ADDRESS  = argv[1]
sendBytes = argv[2]


proID2 = os.fork()
if proID2 == 0:
    os.system('ping -c 20 ' + ADDRESS + ' > testStuff2.txt')
    os._exit(0)

print proID2

finn = True
while finn == True:
time.sleep(1)
finn = os.path.exists("/proc/" + str(proID2))
print os.path.exists("/proc/" + str(proID2))
print 'eeup out of it ' + str(proID2)
```

I think that the os.path.exists() is maybe not the right thing to use.

Thanks.

Comment: Checking the existence of /proc/###/ is no good solution.  How PIDs are issues is not defined.  After your child terminated, the next process started (which may be totally independent from your application) *can* get the same PID.  Typically, they are issued in a turnaround, so with current kernels your solution will work most likely all the time, but you cannot be sure about future kernel versions or in special cases like when you put the computer in sleep mode, or in case your application is stalling for quite some time due to network lag, a non-responding server or similar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To wait for the child process to terminate, use one of the `os.waitXXX()` functions, such as [`os.waitpid()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.waitpid). This method is reliable; as a bonus, it will give you the status information.

Answer (score 10):

While you can use `os.fork()` and `os.wait()` (see below for an example), you are probably better off using methods from the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.

```
import os, sys

child_pid = os.fork()
if child_pid == 0:
    # child process
    os.system('ping -c 20 www.google.com >/tmp/ping.out')
    sys.exit(0)

print "In the parent, child pid is %d" % child_pid
#pid, status = os.wait()
pid, status = os.waitpid(child_pid, 0)
print "wait returned, pid = %d, status = %d" % (pid, status)
```